# Stata to R Replace Values based on Condition

Tags: r, stata

I'm trying to do something very simple in R that I can do in Stata but I can't quite get it right.

Here is my sample of my data

```r
data<-data.frame(
  C1=c(rep(2,5), rep(20,5), rep(70,5)),
  C2=c(rep(20,5), rep(70,5), rep(80,5)),
  year=rep(1990:1994, 3), 
  VAR1=NA,
  VAR2=NA,
  VAR3=NA
)
```

in Stata I can do this

```
replace VAR1=1 if CC1=2 & CC2==20 & year == 1990
replace VAR2=60 if CC1=2 & CC2==20 & year == 1990
replace VAR3=70 if CC1=2 & CC2==20 & year == 1990
```

annoyingly Stata syntax does not allow

```
replace VAR1=1 & VAR2=60 & VAR3=70 if CC1=2 & CC2==20 & year == 1990
```

using the first Stata code

this

```r
data1<-data.frame(C1=c(2),C2=c(20),year=c(1990),VAR1=NA,VAR2=NA,VAR3=NA)
```

becomes this

```r
data2<-data.frame(C1=c(2),C2=c(20),year=c(1990),VAR1=c(1),VAR2=c(60),VAR3=c(70))
```

I can't find anything similar to this problem (it's very likely that I'm not asking/looking for the right phrase)

I'd like to do either the 1st but preferably the 2nd Stata command in R.

Comment: The Stata syntax you want uses `&` in two quite different senses, `&` is a logical operator, not punctuation in a list of things to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep("VAR", names(data))
setDT(data)[C1 == 2 & C2 == 20 & year == 1990, (nm1) := .(1, 60, 70)]
data
#    C1 C2 year VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
# 1:  2 20 1990    1   60   70
# 2:  2 20 1991   NA   NA   NA
# 3:  2 20 1992   NA   NA   NA
# 4:  2 20 1993   NA   NA   NA
# 5:  2 20 1994   NA   NA   NA
# 6: 20 70 1990   NA   NA   NA
# 7: 20 70 1991   NA   NA   NA
# 8: 20 70 1992   NA   NA   NA
# 9: 20 70 1993   NA   NA   NA
#10: 20 70 1994   NA   NA   NA
#11: 70 80 1990   NA   NA   NA
#12: 70 80 1991   NA   NA   NA
#13: 70 80 1992   NA   NA   NA
#14: 70 80 1993   NA   NA   NA
#15: 70 80 1994   NA   NA   NA
```

---

Or another option is to set the key while creating the data.table and then specify the `i` with the values

```
setDT(data, key = c("C1", "C2", "year"))
data[.(2, 20, 1990), (nm1) := .(1, 60, 70)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
i1 <- with(data, C1 == 2 & C2 == 20 & year == 1990)
data %>% 
    select(starts_with("VAR")) %>%
    map2_df(., c(1, 60, 70), ~ replace(.x, i1, .y)) %>%
    bind_cols(data %>% 
               select(1:3), .)
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(C1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70), C2 = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 80), year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
1994L), VAR1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), VAR2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), VAR3 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 3):

If your condition is going to remain the same for all the columns you can calculate them once to get indices in different column and assign the values together.

```
inds <- with(data, C1 == 2 & C2 == 20 & year == 1990)
data[inds, paste0("VAR", 1:3)] <- as.list(c(1, 60, 70))

data
#   C1 C2 year VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
#1   2 20 1990    1   60   70
#2   2 20 1991   NA   NA   NA
#3   2 20 1992   NA   NA   NA
#4   2 20 1993   NA   NA   NA
#5   2 20 1994   NA   NA   NA
#6  20 70 1990   NA   NA   NA
#7  20 70 1991   NA   NA   NA
#8  20 70 1992   NA   NA   NA
#9  20 70 1993   NA   NA   NA
#10 20 70 1994   NA   NA   NA
#11 70 80 1990   NA   NA   NA
#12 70 80 1991   NA   NA   NA
#13 70 80 1992   NA   NA   NA
#14 70 80 1993   NA   NA   NA
#15 70 80 1994   NA   NA   NA
```

If you might have different conditions for different columns you can have a look at `dplyr` package which makes it easier such replacement using pipes

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(VAR1 = replace(VAR1, C1 == 2 & C2 == 20 & year == 1990, 1), 
         VAR2 = replace(VAR2, C1 == 2 & C2 == 20 & year == 1990, 60), 
         VAR3 = replace(VAR3, C1 == 2 & C2 == 20 & year == 1990, 70))
```